# Larax & Zaco: how to kill the giant green crab

Tags: larax-and-zaco

Larax & Zaco is an old dos game by Stefano Zanobi. It's a platformer with destructible scenarios where you advance by catching specific gems/items and bombing the buildings.

I played this in deathmatch mode a lot with my sister, but only recently thought about why:

I could never (and still can't) kill a giant green crab, which is a sort of guardian of a building which is sealed off, and is where the gems are.

**QUESTION: how do i kill the giant green crab?** it drove me nuts, a while ago, and I'd like to play the next levels :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Climb high on the mountain on the left, and throw bombs at the crab.  After 2 minutes it's over.